# Is it possible to pass Array to phonegap plugin in android from javascript interface?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

Is it possible to pass Array to phonegap plugin in android from javascript interface ?
Im using phonegap 2.7 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes it is possible to pass array from Java Script to Native i.e Plugin**

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "service", "action", ["firstArgument", "secondArgument", "thirdArgument",
                     "fourthArgument"]);
```

***The parameters are detailed below:***

`function(winParam) {}:` Success function callback. Assuming your exec call completes successfully, this function is invoked (optionally with any parameters you pass back to it).

`function(error) {}:` Error function callback. If the operation does not complete successfully, this function is invoked (optionally with an error parameter).

`"service":` The service name to call into on the native side. This is mapped to a native class, and it is defined in config.xml.

`"action":` The action name to call into. This is picked up by the native class receiving the exec call, and, depending on the platform, essentially maps to a class's method.

**[Array of Data, separated by ',']**: Arguments to pass into the native environment.